# How do I set multiple array values by index in Scala?

Tags: arrays, scala

Suppose I have a sequence of integers and a number n < 30.  How can I produce an array (of length n) that is 0 in all places except at the indices specified by the sequence (where it should be 1)?

For instance

Input:

```
Seq(1, 2, 5)
7
```

Output:

```
Array(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
scala> val a = Array.fill(7)(0)
a: Array[Int] = Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)

scala> Seq(1,2,5).foreach(a(_) = 1)

scala> a
res1: Array[Int] = Array(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0)
```

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively,

```
scala> val is = Set(1, 2, 5)
is: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(1, 2, 5)

scala> Array.tabulate(10)(i => if (is contains i) 1 else 0)
res0: Array[Int] = Array(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

Comment: Use `is(i)` if you can afford the parens.

Answer (score 2):

```
def makeArray(indices: Seq[Int], size: Int): Array[Int] = Iterable.tabulate(size) {
  case idx if indices contains idx => 1
  case _ => 0
}.toArray

makeArray(Seq(1, 2, 5), size = 7)
```